# Call method on parameter change

Tags: blazor

I have a component than gets data to display from WebAPI using parameter. Parameter comes from parent component and I need to refresh data when parameter's value changes.

```
@if (somedata != null)
{
    <span>@somedata.FirstOrDefault()?.SomeValue</span>
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int SelectedLine
    {
        get => selectedLine;
        set
        {
            if (selectedLine != value)
            {
                selectedLine = value;
                UpdateAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    private int selectedLine;
    private List<SomeData> somedata;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await UpdateAsync();
    }
    private async Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        somedata = await SomeRepo.GetAsync(SelectedLine);
    }
}
```

Code works well but I got warning ("Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed") and I think this is not a very elegant decision. How can it be done right?

Comment: Why do use a Parameter instead of an event ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can  use OnParametersSetAsync() to properly await getting your data.

And then the property doesn't need a setter anymore.

```
[Parameter]
public int SelectedLine { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await UpdateAsync();        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I`ll have many components with 1-2 parameters so this solution works great!

Comment: Is `OnParametersSetAsync` being called every time parameters are getting set, or only once? Sorry I'm a bit lazy to verify myself :) Also to @yirk, make sure you [handle errors properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Comment: @noseratio - every time.